# Template with auto-type return deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have created a templated struct and am trying to overload the binary operators. For some reason the function does not return the correct data type even though the type is correctly casted in between.

```
template<typename T>
struct Number{
    const T value;
    Number(T a) : value(a) {}

    template<typename U>
    auto operator*(Number<U> other){
        auto new_value = value*other.value;
        std::cout << typeid(new_value).name() << std::endl;
        return Number(new_value);
    }
};
```

Now if I perform this operation with the following code called in main. It returns Number of the type of the first one, not number of the higher type.

```
auto b =  Number<int>(6) * Number<double>(2.3); // this should be an int*double=double
std::cout << b.value << typeid(b.value).name() << std::endl;
auto c = Number<double>(2.3) * Number<int>(6);
std::cout << c.value << typeid(c.value).name() << std::endl;
```

Output is as follows:
d
13i
d
13.8d

From what I understand, the incorrect constructor is called when the function return the new `Number(new_value)`. I do not understand how and why this happens as new_value is of the 'correct type'.

Comment: Are you expecting class template argument deduction to take place here? I think you're simply using the injected-class-name.

Comment: I am expecting the Number constructor with T=double called. Ahh, I see. You mean that because the code is in the template it immediately uses T until it 'leaves' the struct?

Comment: @Helv That is correct.

Comment: Maybe there's a lesson here: CTAD adds magic to the language. Magic is great when it works, and utterly mystifying when it doesn't. So if it is important that your code is comprehensible to human readers, you may like to use magic sparingly and with great consideration for the trade-offs. A boring, non-magic solution exists and can be used instead.

Comment: please properly indent your code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside the scope of a template, the template-name is going to stand for the injected class name, and not for the template. So there will not be CTAD, [and that's by design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148915/deduction-guides-and-injected-class-names)

Using `return Number<decltype(new_value)>(new_value);` is the simple workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You are return the first type and not the second type:

```
template<typename U>
auto operator*(Number<U> other){
    auto new_value = value*other.value;
    std::cout << typeid(new_value).name() << std::endl;
    return Number(new_value);
}
```

Even if `new_value` is a double, you are storing it in a `Number<T>`.

Try:

```
template<typename U>
auto operator*(Number<U> other){
    auto new_value = value*other.value;
    std::cout << typeid(new_value).name() << std::endl;
    return Number<decltype(new_value)>(new_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53812808/2069064) points out, within a class template definition, the name of the class refers to the specific class instance (known as the *injected-class-name*) and not the name of the template.

But if you want class template argument deduction to still apply, you can just qualify the name:

```
return ::Number(new_value);
```

`::Number` refers to the class template `Number`, not the specific type `Number<T>`. But this might be a little too magic for other people reading your code, and simply using `Number<decltype(new_value)>(new_value)` has a lot of benefit.